# custom edittext does not change in android

Tags: android, xml

guys i cant seem to understand why my custom edittext does not change in virtual machine and on real device. but in the preview layout it changes. please help thanks in advance.

tetxbox.xml(res/drawable-hdpi/textbox.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/textbox"></item>
```

---

activity_main.xml(res/layout/activity_main.xml)

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="@string/etxt_username"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? What are you expecting to change about it?

Comment: Where is your custom EditText?

Comment: @codeMagic change the layout i mean. i am expecting to change the default style of the edittext to my own style.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 my custom edittext is on the xml

Comment: Try to put your **tetxbox.xml** under **res/drawable/** instead of **res/drawable-hdpi/** --::-- hdpi = high-density ( for screens ~240dpi). So i guess your real device and emulator are low than 240dpi, this is why you don't see your custom EditText changes

Comment: @Rami btw sir there is no drawable folder.

Comment: Tell us, if it solve your problem!

Comment: @Rami sorry for the late reply sir. ahm what i did was directly call the image. i did not pass it to the xml. and now its working. thanks sir "D